# Cannot define proper path for @PropertySource annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I would like to use `@PropertySource` annotation in my Spring project. I do not know what shall be the path for my `ceny.properties` file. I have the following path,

```
@PropertySource("classpath:properties\\ceny.properties")
```

and dictionary structure,

```
C:\Users\X\IdeaProjects\XDxD\src\main\properties\ceny.properties
```

I am using IntelliJ. Where shall I put the `ceny.properties` file. I assume that the classpath is in main.

Comment: In the tutorial that I am whatjing it works, On my project it does not work. I always have an exception: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ceny.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Try putting it in `main/resources` folder. And then `@PropertySource("classpath:ceny.properties")`

Comment: try this `@PropertySource("classpath:src\main\properties\ceny.properties")` or `@PropertySource("file:src\main\properties\ceny.properties")`